# Duplication of data in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a list of data "percesc", which have a repetitive number of DS_DISCIPLINA_DIS (ordered by).

I'm using a class that I found on internet to make a Accordion style of Cards that contains a "Table" for each DS_DISCIPLINA_DIS different records.

So, for each number of DS_DISCIPLINA_DIS records I want a different "Table" to put on each Card.

```html
    PercEsc = await _iAlunoRepository.getPercEscolar(TurmaAtual);
    accordionChildren.clear();
    String discAtual = "";
    List<TableRow> linhas = [];
    for (PercEscModel percesc in PercEsc) {
      if (percesc.DS_DISCIPLINA_DIS != discAtual) {
        if (discAtual != "") {
          Table tabelaNotas = Table(children: linhas);

          linhas.clear();

          var newItem = Accordion(discAtual, tabelaNotas);
          accordionChildren.add(newItem);
        }
        discAtual = percesc.DS_DISCIPLINA_DIS;
        linhas.add(const TableRow(children: [
          Text("Módulo", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
          Text("Designação", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
          Text("Nota", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0))
        ]));
      }

      linha.add(TableRow(children: [
        Text(percesc.DS_ABREVUNID_ORG_UNO, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11.0)),
        Text(percesc.DS_UNID_ORG_UNO, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11.0)),
        Text(percesc.QT_NOTA_AVL.replaceAll(".00", ""),
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11.0))
      ]));

    }
```

if I made this way, all accordionChildren stays with the records of the last DS_DISCIPLINA_DIS.

if I delete "linhas.clear();" line, all accordionChildren stays with all records os all DS_DISCIPLINA_DIS.

I thought that when I write "Table tabelaNotas = Table(children: linha);" I was making a new "tabelaNotas" and the old one was discarded, but it seems that it stays the same.

How can I atribute the different data to each accordionChildren?

Sorry about my english

Let me simplify the question.

if I have this code:

```html
Table tabelaNotas = Table(children: linhas);
var newItem = Accordion(discAtual, tabelaNotas);
accordionChildren.add(newItem);

linhas.clear();
```

"linhas" is a "List" of data to lines of Table

After executing this line ("accordionChildren.add(newItem);"), the first child of accordionChildren has 18 lines.

But after "linhas.clear();", accordionChildren will have no lines.

I understand that flutter works with reference to objects, so if I define "Table tabelaNotas = Table(children: linhas);", the content of table wil be somehow "linked" to "linhas", and if I clear linhas, I am also clearing the content of Table.

But I want to clear (delete) "linhas" without loosing that data on accordionCildren.

Probably is something very simple, but as before last week I never had worked with flutter, I'm a little bit confused with this situation.

If anyone could help me, I will be forever grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

```html
List<TableRow> linhasAux = List.from(linhas);
tabelaNotas = Table(children: linhasAux);
var newItem = Accordion(discAtual, tabelaNotas);
accordionChildren.add(newItem);

linhas.clear();
```

this way, I made a copy (linhasAux) of List (linhas) and added the copy to table. Now I can clear "linhas" without loose the information that were already on Table.